# Determining $\lim\sup_{n→∞} q_n$ and $\lim\inf_{n→∞}q_n$ for a countable set $\mathbb Q ∩ [0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences, limsup-and-liminf

Could anyone help me with this question?

Let $\{q_n\}_{n∈\mathbb N}$ be an enumeration of the countable set  $\mathbb Q ∩ [0, 1]$.
Determine $\lim\sup_{n→∞} q_n$ and $\lim\inf_{n→∞}q_n$

So my guess is that any element in this interval is an accumulation point, so $\lim\sup_{n→∞} q_n= 1$ and $\lim\inf_{n→∞}q_n = 0$. But how can I prove that?

Comment: Do you have any guesses?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$, and $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ give you the biggest and smallest limit points of $\{q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ respectively

Comment: @geetha290krm So my guess is that any element in this interval is an accumulation point, so lim sup (qn) = 1 and lim inf (qn) = 0. But how can I prove that?

Comment: Use the definition of an accumulation point.

Answer (score 1):

according to the definition of an accumulation point, you would need to proof that every element of {q} is a partial sequence that converges, so that every element of {q} is an accumulation point.
but how to show that?
this follows somehow out of the statement that **Q** is dense in [0,1], does it?